# File deletion on NTFS vs ext4

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs, ext4

How does deletion of files on NTFS compare to deletion on ext4 in terms of basic methodology?

This may be too broad of a question, so alternatively, I was looking at the Veracrypt docs

> On Windows, make sure you have not deleted any files within a volume within which you intend to create a hidden volume (the cluster bitmap scanner does not detect deleted files)

And wondered what Windows does differently in deletion that would make deleted files "not detectable" (as deleted, I presume) by a bitmap scanner.